How do I run a Python file on my Mac that reads and writes txt files to my external hardrive?
I currently have a folder full of epubs that I would like to read, a folder of epubs I've already read and would like to read again, and a corresponding file with the names of the epub files in each. The problem is, these folders are on my external hard-drive only. What I want to do is to have my script parse the list of epubs in these folders and create an up-to-date copy in my downloads folder, where another bit of code will take care of any copies I download if I forget that I already have a copy in my library.
I imagine that this fix will have to make use of the os or shutil modules, and I've been told to be very careful when making use of them. I do understand that this might also require use of Bash, which I have some minor inkling of knowledge in.

Why does it matter that the files are on an external drive?  It's just another directory, right?

Can you be more precise about the problem you're encountering? If I have to guess, I think maybe your issue is just not knowing how to find the path to the drive? Maybe this answer will help.

This question is similar to: Access file in external hard drive using python on mac. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I'm not too sure on what your asking but maybe this is what you want?
import os
import shutil

# Paths
external_drive_folder = '/path/to/external/drive/folder'
downloads_folder = '/path/to/downloads/folder'
read_list_file = '/path/to/read_list.txt'
to_read_list_file = '/path/to/to_read_list.txt'

# Read the list of epub files
def read_file_list(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        return [line.strip() for line in file]

read_list = read_file_list(read_list_file)
to_read_list = read_file_list(to_read_list_file)

# Combine the lists
all_epub_files = read_list + to_read_list

# Function to copy files
def copy_files(file_list, src_folder, dst_folder):
    for file_name in file_list:
        src_path = os.path.join(src_folder, file_name)
        dst_path = os.path.join(dst_folder, file_name)
    
        # Check if the file already exists in the destination folder
        if os.path.exists(dst_path):
            print(f"File {file_name} already exists in the destination folder.")
        else:
            try:
                shutil.copy2(src_path, dst_path)
                print(f"Copied {file_name} to {dst_folder}.")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error copying {file_name}: {e}")

# Copy files from external drive to downloads folder
copy_files(all_epub_files, external_drive_folder, downloads_folder)

I'm not too sure on how well this code will run, but hope it works out for you.
